# Pop the back of a queue without using a deque

Tags: c++, queue, back

Is it possible to pop the back of a queue in C++ without using a deque? How would this be done?

```
queue<int> myQ;

myQ.pop(back());
```

I know this doesn't work, but hopefully it gives an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is a so-called container *adaptor* class, and can use any class which implements the same interface as the default [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) class, including [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It also means it must use an underlying container class for the actual storage, either a standard [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or a custom container with the correct interface.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.

Use a `std::deque` if you want to be able to do this.